# C# Decrease or increase variable (like a point buy system)?

Tags: c#, variables, points

My brain's absolutely fried here. sorry for the (no doubt) obvious question, but I can't see the wood for the trees!

I have a variable that acts as a "Point Pool". A numericupdown control affects this point pool. if I increase the numupdown, the point pool decreases and vice versa. I just can't get my head around the logic :(

Here's my "Code" for what it's worth...

```
private void numJobSkill1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int difference = (int)(numJobSkill1.Value - numJobSkill1.Minimum);

        /* if (numJobSkill1.Value > numJobSkill1.Minimum)
        {

            POINTPOOL = POINTPOOL - 1;

        } 
        else
        {
            POINTPOOL = POINTPOOL + 1;
        } */

        lblPOINTPOOL.Text = PLAYERPOINTS.ToString();

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now my brain is fried! what are numJobSkill1.Value and numJobSkill1.Minimum and why cast the difference to an int? what is the question?

Comment: ok, to clarify. POINTPOOL = 100. numJobSkill = 5. When jobskill is increased by 10, POINTPOOL = 90. If jobskill is decreased to 7, POINTPOOL = 93.

Answer (score 1):

To determine whether the value has been increased or decreased you need to remember the last value.

```
// initialize this with the initial value of the UpDownControl
private int _previousValue;

private void numJobSkill1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    int currentValue = numJobSkill1.Value;
    _pointPool -= currentValue - _previousValue;
    _previousValue = currentValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Daniel. Almost there, I just need to fix it so it reacts when the user enters a number rather than clicking the spin box. Thanks again!

Comment: @HarryBall: You are welcome. Please check my edit, it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to handle this would make the PointPool a function instead of a variable where the return value is the TotalPointsAvailable - TotalPointAllocated, the TotalPointsAllocated is the value in the numJobSkill1 but it could easily be the sum of several updowns.

```
private void numJobSkill1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PLAYERPOINTS = PointPool();
    lblPOINTPOOL.Text = PLAYERPOINTS.ToString();

}

private Int32 TotalPointsAvailable;

private Int32 TotalPointsAllocated()
{
   //Value is a decimal
   return (Int32)numJobSkill1.Value;
}

private Int32 PointPool()
{
    return TotalPointsAvailable-TotalPointsAllocated();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
private void numJobSkill1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int difference = (int)(numJobSkill1.Value - numJobSkill1.Minimum);

        if (difference > 0)
        {
            difference--;
        }
        else
        {
            difference++;
        }

        lblPOINTPOOL.Text = difference.ToString();

    }
```